# Selecting all IDs with value lower than max ID value for rows with duplicate column value and using cursor to delete them

Tags: sql

I'm currently working on an SQL query to extract specific rows from a set of what seems to be duplicate rows in a table and then delete them.

My mission here is to delete the rows with lower value id for rows that have the same "ItemID" so to speak.

What I've managed to do is this:

Select all duplicate rows and return their ID (Internal DB ID) and their ItemID.

[image]

What i want to do after that is:

(Pseudo explanation)
FOREACH DISTINCT "ItemID" SELECT ALL IDs < MAX(ID (foreach ITEMID))
So to speak....

So i want to end up with something like this:

referring to the example in the picture above - for the ItemID "3105067", i would only like to have the ID "290120" returning as one of the rows in the results as for ItemID "3105067"
that "ID" is the lowest value of the Two existing for the same ItemID.

What I'm trying to achieve here is to get a list to run though with a cursor for each ID that isn't the lates to then delete the duplicates for.

Answer (score 0):

*to delete the rows with lower value id for rows that have the same "ItemID"*:

```
delete from tablename t1
where exists (select * from tablename t2
              where t2.ItemID = t1.ItemID
                and t2.Id > t1.Id)
```